# MLE for difference of two binomial success probabilities

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

If $X \sim Binomial (n_1, p_1)$ and $Y \sim Binomial(n_2, p_2)$ and $X,Y$ are independent, how do I find the MLE for $\phi = p_1 - p_2$?

I tried finding the joint distribution for $X,Y$ but, I didn't see how that would shed light on $\phi$ as it is the difference between the two success probabilities. I'm stuck on how to approach this problem, and would appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since  and  are independent, the difference between the MLEs of 1 and 2 should be the MLE of .

Let y1 and y2 denote the numbers of "successes" for  and . The MLEs of 1 and 2 are y1/1 and y2/n2 respectively.

Thus, the MLE of  is y1/n1 - y2/n2.

Comment: Do you have a citation for this statement: "Since  and  are independent, the difference between the MLEs of 1 and 2 should be the MLE of "?

Comment: We can use the plug-in estimator property of the MLE. So if the MLE of X is x/n1 and for Y is y/n2, then the MLE of X-Y is x/n1 - x/n2